# How do I remove NetBeans IDE from Fedora 15?

Tags: linux, fedora, netbeans

I have two version of NetBeans installed in Fedora 15. I am unable to open them for the past three days.

I would like to remove the existing ones completely but they were not installed via yum. How do I remove them?

I tried the following, but in Gnome 3 if I type NetBeans it still shows two icons.

```
# rm -fr netbeans-dev-20110*
# rm -fr /usr/share/applications/netbeans-Build 201105230400.desktop
# rm -fr /usr/share/applications/netbeans-Build 201107150600.desktop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation folder of Netbeans should have a uninstall.sh to remove it , run it to remove your installation .